# Issue with getting user id in Yii application

Tags: php, yii

I have a site running in production which is working fine and I am making a few changes to code so I'm copying it to localhost. The site has a user management system and requires login. Once user logs in, they are redirected to mysite.com/admin/index.

The user validation is taking place and authenticate class in UserIdentity class return errorcode as 0. However, when user goes to WebUser class, it returns an empty value when I check $this->id. Also, Yi::app()->user->id does not exist.

Following are relevant sections of my code:

In main.php

```
'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            // 'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'class' => 'WebUser',
            'loginUrl'=>array('site/login'),
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

In UserIdentity.php

```
private $_group;
private $_id;

public function getId(){
  return $this->_id;
}

public function authenticate($seeker = false, $queryid = false){
  //Retrieve seeker Login

  $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('login_name'=>$this->username, 'status' => 0));

  //Invalid username
  if($record===null){
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
  }
  //Invalid password
  else if($record->password !== $record->encryptPassword($this->password) && $record->password !== $record->encryptPassword($this->password, true)){
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
  }
  //Valid login
  else{
    //Use new encryption
    if($record->password === $record->encryptPassword($this->password, true))
      $record->resetPassword($this->password);
    $this->_id       = $record->id;
    $this->_group    = $record->group;
    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
  }
  if($this->errorCode == self::ERROR_NONE){
    $auth=Yii::app()->authManager;
    try{ $role=$auth->createRole($this->_group); } catch(Exception $e){}

    if(!$auth->isAssigned($this->_group,$this->_id)){
      if($auth->assign($this->_group,$this->_id)){
        Yii::app()->authManager->save();
      }
    }
  }

  return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

In my SiteController.php, when I check for userid after login, it returns correct value but after the user is redirected to admin/index and I check value for userid, it doesn't show any value.

Can someone suggest what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

code below save url state, 
request `admin/edit/3` -> redirect to `login page` -> redirect to `admin/edit/3` 
request `login page` -> redirect `admin/index`

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->getUser()->getReturnUrl('admin/index'));
```

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: You stay on `site.com/admin/edit/3` and your session has been expired, press `f5` and after success login you come back to `site.com/admin/edit/3` not  `admin/index`

Comment: Right now, when I'm at site/login, I see the login form and it redirects me to admin/index on validation. Going to site/admin/edit/3 just gives me a 404.

Comment: `admin/edit/3` just an example of your private page different from `admin/index`

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: Imagine you have 2 pages (admin/index, admin/add) with private access.
You stay on http://example.com/admin/add, copy url and press logout, after paste url to adress bar and press enter.
Site will redirect you to site/login after success login you will on page http://example.com/admin/add

If you open new browser's tab and go to http://example.com/site/login after success login you will on page http://example.com/admin/index

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean but I don't think that is the issue. Even when I access /admin/index directly, I still get redirected to site/login. Also, I tried var_dump and die() to check user redirect url before redirection and it should be redirecting to admin/index.

Answer (score 0):

If deciding only from your code and nothing else matters, it looks like this validation

```
Yii::app()->user->returnUrl == '/index.php'
```

is always false. You can simply debug this by stopping your code at this pint in debugger, or by simply putting „dump'n'stop code“ :)

```
var_dump(
    Yii::app()->user->returnUrl == '/index.php',
    Yii::app()->user->returnUrl
);
die();
```

before this line

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl == '/index.php'? '/admin/index': Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```